# order by not working on alias column in mysql query with union all query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUM(T1.approve_con) AS compl_rec,
SUM(T1.payout) AS payout,
SUM(T1.reversal) AS reversal,
T1.app_id,
T1.end_user,
T1.created
FROM (
    (SELECT app_id,end_user,created,
    approve_conversions AS `approve_con`,
    '0' AS reversal,
    payout AS payout
    FROM app_end_users 
    WHERE publisher_id=1625 
    AND app_id=57)
UNION ALL
    (SELECT opinongold_survey_response.app_id,
    opinongold_survey_response.user_id AS end_user,
    opinongold_survey_response.movement AS created,
    (CASE WHEN opinongold_survey_response.survey_status= 'Completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `approve_con`,
    (CASE WHEN opinongold_survey_response.survey_status= 'Rejected' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS reversal,
    (CASE WHEN opinongold_survey_response.survey_status= 'Completed' THEN payout ELSE 0 END) AS payout                                  
    FROM opinongold_survey_response
    WHERE  pub_id=1625 
    AND app_id=57)
) AS T1
GROUP BY T1.app_id,T1.end_user
ORDER BY `approve_con` DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

above is my mysql query order by is not working on approve_con, payout, reversal column
please let me where i am doing wrong in this query.

Comment: After GROUP BY your `approve_con` is not available. PS. Incomplete GROUP BY. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY then fix your query.

Comment: did not understand can you explain me change in my query if possible ? @Akina

Comment: 1) Either add `T1.created` to GROUP BY expression or remove it from the output list or retrieve MIN/MAX of it instead. 2) Imagine that a group contains 2 different `approve_con` values. What of these values would be used in ORDER BY? I think that you'd use `ORDER BY compl_rec`.